# Reacthook loop traversal occurs many times, rendering speed is very slow

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I try to show the array in the map loop. Filtergroup is a very large array. When I click to select one of them, the rendering is very slow. How can I solve it? (I tried to use usememo, but it didn't work)

```
const FilterAccordionItem: React.FC<FilterAccordionItemProps> = (props) => {
const { filterGroup, toggleSelect, selectedSet, ...rest } = props;
const imageSelectMode = filterGroup.selectType === SelectTypeEnum.Image;

const items = useMemo(() => {
    return (
        <VStack py="12px" maxH="400px" pl="3px" overflowY="scroll">
            {filterGroup.conditionList.map((item, idx) => (
                <>
                    {console.log('render  filterGroup filterGroup')}
                    <HStack w="full" alignItems="left" key={idx} my="6px">
                        <Checkbox
                            colorScheme="purple"
                            mr="16px"
                            isChecked={selectedSet.has(item.conditionKey)}
                            onChange={() => toggleSelect(item.conditionKey)}
                        />
                        <Text fontSize="14px" color="darkGray">
                            {item.name}
                        </Text>
                        <Text fontSize="16px" color="gray.500">
                            ({item.total})
                        </Text>
                    </HStack>
                </>
            ))}
        </VStack>
    );
}, [filterGroup, toggleSelect, selectedSet]);
return (
    <AccordionItem ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you memoize the entire list. This way each state change causes re-rendering of **all** elements instead of re-rendering only those that have their selection changed. What you should try instead is to factor out the code inside the map function into a separate component and wrap that component with `React.memo`. The component should accept a plain boolean flag that indicates whether an item is selected or not and only re-renders if the item's selection was changed.

Here's a quick demo of this approach. Open the console and you will see that every time you click the button all items rendered following the original approach get re-rendered. The optimized approach re-renders only those elements that have their selection state changed.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-71870292

Comment: It's really not slow now. I rewritten the code in your way. It's amazing. You're awesome,thanks a lot.